# How to create a unique array of json objects with sort on a field?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

How can I filler the below array on common `id` and output should have unique and latest history number

```js
const input = [{
  "id": 134116,
  "user": "admin",
  "historyno": "134116-0"
}, {
  "id": 134132,
  "user": "admin",
  "historyno": "134132-0"
}, {
  "id": 134132,
  "user": "admin",
  "historyno": "134132-1"
}, {
  "id": 134133,
  "user": "admin",
  "historyno": "134133-0"
}, {
  "id": 134133,
  "user": "admin",
  "historyno": "134133-1"
}];

let output = [];
let tempId;

for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
  if (input[i].id === tempId) {
    //do nothing
  } else {
    output.push(input[i]);
    tempId = input[i].id;
  }
}

console.log(output);
```

Expected Output

```
[
  {
    "id": 134116,
    "user": "admin",
    "historyno": "134116-0"
  },
  {
    "id": 134132,
    "user": "admin",
    "historyno": "134132-1"
  },
  {
    "id": 134133,
    "user": "admin",
    "historyno": "134133-1"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reduce the array to a Map, using the `id` as key, and then convert back by spreading the `Map.values()` iterator to an array.

This solution assumes that the array is presorted by history numbers:

```js
const input = [{"id":134116,"user":"admin","historyno":"134116-0"},{"id":134132,"user":"admin","historyno":"134132-0"},{"id":134132,"user":"admin","historyno":"134132-1"},{"id":134133,"user":"admin","historyno":"134133-0"},{"id":134133,"user":"admin","historyno":"134133-1"}];

const output = [...input.reduce((r, o) => r.set(o.id, o), new Map).values()];

console.log(output);
```

This solution handles unsorted arrays by only replacing the current item in the map if `historyno` is greater:

```js
const input = [{"id":134116,"user":"admin","historyno":"134116-0"},{"id":134132,"user":"admin","historyno":"134132-0"},{"id":134132,"user":"admin","historyno":"134132-1"},{"id":134133,"user":"admin","historyno":"134133-0"},{"id":134133,"user":"admin","historyno":"134133-1"}];

const getHistoryNo = ({ historyno }) => +historyno.split('-')[1];

const output = [...input.reduce((r, o) => {
  const prev = r.get(o.id);
  
  if(!prev || getHistoryNo(o) > getHistoryNo(prev)) r.set(o.id, o);
  
  return r;
}, new Map).values()];

console.log(output);
```

Comment: where does this sort for `"historyno":"134132-1"` Its working but dont know how

Comment: @dota2pro - is your array ordered, ie - latest history numbers would come after previous history numbers in the array?

Answer (score 2):

You can split `historyno` by `-` and take the second element, compare it with previously set same id's value, if the current one is higher than last one use the current one else use the last one

```js
const input = [{"id": 134116,"user": "admin","historyno": "134116-0"}, {  "id": 134132,  "user": "admin","historyno": "134132-0"}, { "id": 134132,"user": "admin","historyno": "134132-1"}, {  "id": 134133,  "user": "admin",  "historyno": "134133-0"
}, { "id": 134133,"user": "admin","historyno": "134133-1"}];

let final = input.reduce((op,inp)=>{
  op[inp.id] = op[inp.id] || inp
  let lastHisotry = +op[inp.id].historyno.split('-')[1]
  let currentHistory = +inp.historyno.split('-')[1]
  op[inp.id].historyno = currentHistory > lastHisotry ? inp.historyno : op[inp.id].historyno
  return op
},{})
console.log(final);
```

***Note:-*** If your array is already ordered you don't need this split logic, you can simply do

```js
const input = [{"id": 134116,"user":"admin","historyno": "134116-0"}, {  "id": 134132,  "user":"admin","historyno": "134132-0"}, { "id": 134132,"user": "admin","historyno": "134132-1"}, {  "id": 134133,  "user": "admin",  "historyno": "134133-0"}, { "id": 134133,"user": "admin","historyno": "134133-1"}];

let final = input.reduce((op,inp) => {
   op[inp.id] = inp
   return op
},{})

console.log(final);
```

Comment: @CodeManiac +1 for your good answer and I'm curious to know about the `+` before `op[inp.id].historyno.split('-')[1]`.

Comment: @MH2K9 `+` used for coercing string to numeric values

Comment: @dota2pro yeah sure no problem, at present other answer do not consider order, it is considering `input` array is always in desired order of history, i.e latest one at end, here's one which uses sorting and see the results [`Test with sorting`](http://jsben.ch/KU5Ib)

Answer (score 0):

```
var resultObj = input.reduce((prev, next) => {
    if(prev.hasOwnProperty(next.id)) {
       const currentLatest = prev[next.id];
        // Your logic to check if 'currentLatest' is the latest one or the 'next'
    } else {
        prev[next.id] = next;
    }

    return prev;
}, {});

var result = Object.values(resultObj)
```