# How to reduce an array from Right to Left?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

How Can i reduce the array from Right to Left so that I get this output instead of the snippet?

```
[{
  "id": 134116,
  "user": "admin",
  "historyno": "134116-0"
}, {
  "id": 134132,
  "user": "admin",
  "historyno": "134132-0"
}, {
  "id": 134133,
  "user": "admin",
  "historyno": "134133-0"
}];
```

```js
const input = [{"id":134116,"user":"admin","historyno":"134116-0"},{"id":134132,"user":"admin","historyno":"134132-0"},{"id":134132,"user":"admin","historyno":"134132-1"},{"id":134133,"user":"admin","historyno":"134133-0"},{"id":134133,"user":"admin","historyno":"134133-1"}];

const output = [...input.reduce((r, o) => r.set(o.id, o), new Map).values()];

console.log(output);
```

I got this code from an earlier [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57169776/5724889)

Comment: .reverse() the array first

Comment: The answers here are pretty much going to be RTFM. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/ReduceRight

Comment: Are you certain that you will **always** prefer the right most item?

Comment: @dota2pro So you will never process an array like this: https://pastebin.com/2n9qHz8F?

Comment: One solution here is to find another characteristic other than the position of the element in the array. For example, maybe you always want `historyno` that ends in `0`. Using this rule, you can just make your call back more sophisticated.

Comment: @dota2pro In general, relying on the order of an array for processing like this leads to brittle code. I suggest creating a more robust call back for your `reduce()` such as checking the value of `historyno`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice yes like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/57169776/5724889

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not take [`Array#reduceRight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduceRight)?

```js
const
    input = [{ id: 134116, user: "admin", historyno: "134116-0" }, { id: 134132, user: "admin", historyno: "134132-0" }, { id: 134132, user: "admin", historyno: "134132-1" }, { id: 134133, user: "admin", historyno: "134133-0" }, { id: 134133, user: "admin", historyno: "134133-1" }],
    output = [...input.reduceRight((r, o) => r.set(o.id, o), new Map).values()];

console.log(output);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can swap your `Array.reduce()` with `Array.reduceRight()`

Reference: [MDN: Array.reduceRight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduceRight)